# Attachments are stored in base64 format in Bugzilla when uploading using XML-RPC

Tags: xml-rpc, bugzilla

I'm writing a XML-RPC interface for Bugzilla where users can create bugs in Bugzilla using an Excel macro. This is working fine. But if the user uploads a screenshot and adds it as attachment to the bug, the image cannot be displayed in the browser.
I already asked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13516982/add-an-attachment-to-bugzilla-using-xml-rpc-in-vba). Now I found that the base64 encoded data is not converted back to binary before saving into the database.
At first I thought that the XML file might not be correct (i.e. the data type for the image is `<string>` instead of `<base64>` but I verified that the XML is correct. The data type is `<base64>`). But still, the data is stored in the database in base64 format.
When manually uploading a sceenshot from the website, the screenshot data in the database is binary.
So I think that the XML-RPC framework should convert the base64-encoded image data back to 8 bit binary. But that's not the case.
Does anyone have an idea what else might be wrong?

Comment: Have you manage to solve this issue ? I am not sure if it is internal API's issue, but I've written a comment#33 in Bugzilla where they have wrote this API's method. https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=412074

Comment: No, I've given up... Btw, your comment has already been answered. They say you did not declare the content to be base64...